# Symfony2 + FOSUSerBundle: redirection doesn't work

Tags: symfony

I use symfony2 and FOS UserBundle.

I have followed the FOSUSerBundle docs from `https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md` but I have no redirection if I'm going to a specific page.

I mean, I have to be redirected to `http/myapp/login` when I type `http/myapp/myspecificPage/toto` but not. Even if I 'm not logged into my app.

My NamespaceLoginBundle extends to FOSUser.

Here my files `routing.yml`:

```
login: 
    pattern: /login
    defaults: { _controller: NamespaceLoginBundle:Welcome:login }

login_check: 
    pattern: /login_check    
    defaults: { _controller: NamespaceLoginBundle:Welcome:checkUser }

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
    prefix: /

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /change-password
```

and security.yml

```
security:
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    access_control:
        # Liste des pages accessibles à tous les utilisateurs (ne pas toucher)
        - { path: ^/_wdt/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_profiler/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/js/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/css/, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login_check$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resseting$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # PAGES ACCESSIBLES AUX ADMINISTRATEURS
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }

        # PAGES ACCESSIBLES AUX UTILISATEURS CONNECTES
        - { path: ^/change-password, role: ROLE_USER }

        # PAGES ACCESSIBLES A TOUS
        - { path: ^.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

    acl:
        connection: default
```

I have tried some modification but doesn't work.

Any help please.

See ya

Sam

Comment: You allowed to access all pages except for admin and change-password by the `^.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` rule..

Comment: even if I remove - { path: ^.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY } it doesn't work

Comment: You need to specify roles, not remove it. `- { path: ^/.*, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }` where IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY is authenticated by typing login and password, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED is a user that selected 'remember me' on the last login

Comment: Hi, thanks, now it's work... I have changed the last line by yours and it works. Thanks meze

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify roles

`- { path: ^/.*, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY] }`

where:

IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY is authenticated by typing login and password, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED is a user that selected 'remember me' on the last login

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : first time, wrong answer x)

You need to set your `access_role` in order to allow anonymous user only on the login page :

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/logout, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: Hi I've tried to remove this line but I have this error: "La page n'est pas redirigée correctement" means "The redirection is not correct"

Comment: My bad, I was false by saying to delete `anonymous: true` ; I edit my answer ;)
(And I know what it means, I'm french =P)